# `enable_query_strings` is Not Working Properly

Tags: codeigniter, http-status-code-404, xdebug

I'm trying to use CodeIgniter, and xdebug. When I type in the following URL:

```
http://localhost/redux/index.php
```

xdbug works well. When I go to following URL:

```
http://localhost/redux/index.php?
```

I receive the following 404 error message:

```
XDEBUG_SESSION_START=ECLIPSE_DBGP&KEY=124466969367132
```

Eclipse lanches Firefox with the second, wrong URL, and then I have to change it. I'm using `enable_query_strings = TRUE`, but I'm still getting the error. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get this working perfectly, use:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "PATH_INFO";
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```

Comment: Working on an OOOLD project, and I needed this info. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have both

$config['uri_protocol'] = "QUERY_STRING"; or $config['uri_protocol']    = "REQUEST_URI";

and

$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;

If that doesn't work try changing your URI Chars to this

$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-?';

Comment: hi wiebrsk, the one that worked was "PATH_INFO", but thanks for trying anyway