# SimpleTest with CodeIgniter -- won't identify file -- variables die?

Tags: php, codeigniter, netbeans, simpletest

I am trying to use SimpleTest with CodeIgniter, using code supplied by [maroonbytes](http://www.maroonbytes.com/codeigniter/ultimate-codeigniter-setup/).  I am using LAMP and NetBeans 6.9.

The test.php page loads up in my browser.  I have a stub test in place and it shows in the drop-down selections.  When I try to run it, I get 2 PHP errors:

> Message:
>   include_once(/var/www/sparts3/main/tests/basic_test_v.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory
>
> Message: include_once():
>   Failed opening
>   '/var/www/sparts3/main/tests/basic_test_v.php'
>   for inclusion
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')

The path is wrong -- **basic_test_v.php** is in a subfolder **/tests/views**.

The debugger points to this in **test.php**:

```
function add_test($file, &$test)
```

For some reason NetBeans does not expose the value of $file at this point.  Does this mean it's empty?

I've already jimmied a line of code because it gets me past a Code 404 Page Not Found.  it seemed the debugger GET was causing the validator to fail.  So I added a criteria, in my ignorant way (I'm sure it should be a handled exception or something):

```
if ($this->uri->uri_string == '' || $this->uri->uri_string == 'XDEBUG_SESSION_START')
    {   ...  }
```

How can I solve this?  BTW, this is attempted to solve [my other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845340/codeigniter-and-simpletest-how-to-make-my-first-test), which I will update; seemed best to make this a discrete question.

---

**UPDATE 1:**  I've been using the Web Developer add-in (Firefox) to experiment with the POST entries.  I believe these are being mishandled in the code.  It still appears NetBeans is balking on showing some string variables while debugging; this is frustrating.

**UPDATE 2:**  It seems to me that valid code processing stops at the same point NetBeans stops displaying variables.  I am stepping through **test.php**.   I am partway through a function, **add_test($file, &$test)**.  This functions opens with an if statement; that finishes well, and I can see the variables.  Then a new if statement:

```
if (file_exists($implementation))
{
    require_once ($implementation); ...
```

As soon as I'm on that line, 2 things happen:

1. The Variables display in NetBeans goes blank
   except for SuperGlobals
2. The code behaves as if
   **$implementation** is an empty variable

I added a statement just above these lines:

```
$implementation = 'http://var/www/sparts3/main/tests/views/basic_test_view.php';
```

This doesn't change anything.  The browser output is the same whether I'm using NetBeans/Xdebug or not.

So it's starting to look like a PHP processing glitch.  Do those exist?  I may try uploading and trying from host service -- for diagnostic clues only, and cheerlessly, because CI without the ability to debug is of no interest to me.

---

**UPDATE 3:**  I tried everything out on a WAMP PC.  Same browser results (plus some "deprecated" errors, something to do with PHP 4 vs. 5).  I think I can debug on that PC (if Xdebug is functioning), but there seems little point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you renamed basic_test_v.php to basic_test_view.php? the code expects your files to be named and stored right.

**UPDATE 1** (yes im bored)

> I've already jimmied a line of code
>   because it gets me past a Code 404
>   Page Not Found. it seemed the debugger
>   GET was causing the validator to fail.
>   So I added a criteria, in my ignorant
>   way (I'm sure it should be a handled
>   exception or something):

```
if ($this->uri->uri_string == '' || $this->uri->uri_string == 'XDEBUG_SESSION_START') {   ...  }
```

> How can I solve this? BTW, this is attempted to solve my
>   other post, which I will update;
>   seemed best to make this a discrete
>   question.

The "right" solution to this issue is:
set `$config['uri_protocol'] = "AUTO";` to `$config['uri_protocol'] = "PATH_INFO";`
and `$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;` to `$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;`
in the config.php (read the comment above those settings, they very helpful)

After a deeper look at test.php i can tell you that your test files should be named like this:

%name%_%type%_test.php (where %type% is singular)

to make it more clear here an example:

we've got a controller welcome placed in the file welcome.php
the test for this controller should be named **welcome_controller**_test.php and stored under tests/controllers/

the test.php script tries to load the test file and the tested file automatically.
But in my opinion it needs to be corrected.

I've changed function get_loader_id and add_test like follows

```
function get_loader_id($file, $type) {
   $loader_id = str_replace("_{$type}_test.php", "", basename($file));
   return $loader_id;
}
function add_test($file, &$test) {
   $implementation = '';
   if (preg_match('/_controller/', $file)) {
      $controller = get_loader_id($file, 'controller');
      $implementation = APPLICATION . 'controllers/' . $controller . '.php';
   } elseif (preg_match('/_model/', $file)) {
      $model = get_loader_id($file, 'model');
      $implementation = APPLICATION . 'models/' . $model . '_model.php';
   } elseif (preg_match('/_view/', $file)) {
      $view = get_loader_id($file, 'view');
      $implementation = APPLICATION . 'views/' . $view . '.php';
   } elseif (preg_match('/_helper/', $file)) {
      $helper = get_loader_id($file, 'helper');
      $implementation = APPLICATION . 'helpers/' . $helper . '.php';
   } elseif (preg_match('/_library/', $file)) {
      $library = get_loader_id($file, 'library');
      $implementation = APPLICATION . 'libraries/' . $library . '.php';
   }
   if (file_exists($implementation)) {
      require_once ($implementation);
   }
   $test->addFile($file);
}
```

if you're following the filename conventions all should run just fine
(i've tested it on an macbook with zend server ce, xdebug, simpletest and netbeans 6.9)

Comment: Thanks for the work and the advice on several points.  May your boredom ever reward those around you.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're trying to load is a view, have you tried to use `$this->load->view('basic_test_view');` ?